# DraggableScrollableView and GoogleMaps - Maps showing as white blank page

Tags: flutter

I am trying to use DraggableScrollableSheet as a Scaffold bottomSheet, and a body with Google Maps, but no luck so far. Any tips what could be wrong?

```
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Meeting"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            GoogleMap(
              markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
              // YOUR MARKS IN MAP
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                  target: LatLng(47.502941, 18.999161),
                  zoom: 1),
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              zoomControlsEnabled: true,

            ),
          ],
        ),
        bottomSheet:             DraggableScrollableSheet(
          initialChildSize: 0.3,
          minChildSize: 0.1,
          maxChildSize: 0.9,
          builder: (context, scrollController) {
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Card(
                 Text("test"),
            );
          },
        ),
        ,
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
          iconSize: 26,
          items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.close),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.check),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what is going wrong. But the way I've always used a draggable sheet is by putting it in a stack with the main view. You could try that. If the problem is related to google map then you could check the map api key is set properly or not.

Comment: Thanks! The key is fine :)

Comment: Just use Stack brother, I checked with stack it works, but if you put it in the bottomsheet then it takes the whole screen and becomes white